# Set default undefined values for non-required fields in form using yup and react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, frontend, react-hook-form

Now I have written some wrapper for Yup.

```js
Yup.addMethod(Yup.string, 'format', function format() {
    return this.transform((value) => (value === '' ? undefined : value));
});

export const YupString = Yup.string().format();

const ValidationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    field1: YupString,
    field2: YupString,
    field3: YupString,
});
```

Thus, the fields field1, field2, field3 will be **undefined**, and the field field4 will be **""**.

My wrapper checks if the string is empty, and if it is empty, then sets undefined. The problem is that the wrapper needs to be used for each field in the form, and this is not very convenient. Is there a way to configure form validation so that undefined is put in empty fields by default when submitting?